# Laravel can't put a document in LocalStack s3

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, localstack

Storage::disk('s3')->put('file.txt','Contents'). Doesn't see file.txt in the docker container

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrChp.png)
That docker config I have, but When I put command in terminal 'aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3 cp text.txt s3://bucket' It works. By using only Storage::disk('s3')->put('file.txt','Contents') It is not work at all. Can you have recommendations for me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

What is your AWS_ENDPOINT in laravel ?

You need to call the service localstack and not the localhost when you are inside docker network.

So in your laravel .env you need to change the `AWS_ENDPOINT="http://localstack:4566/"`